# Connecting to a custom XSockets controller fails

Tags: xsockets.net

I've done a fair amount of research on this but can't figure out what's wrong. The official documentation (Server API and Plugins) isn't helping me much here.

I have my solution laid out like the following:

- XSocketsControllers

  - Defines long-running controller A, and standard controller B
- WebServer
  (references XSocketsControllers)

Since the documentation says XSockets will discover anything of interest by itself under bin (where the assemblies are being copied), my Web.Config has the following:

```
<add key="XSockets.PluginCatalog" value=""/>
<add key="XSockets.PluginFilter" value="*.dll"/>
```

My bootstrapper runs OK, and if I debug the server container I can see the XSocketPlugins property of my IXBaseServerContainer contains my controllers A and B, BUT if I try connecting from the browser to controller B, for instance, the connection is established but the frame says "The handler name was not found in loaded plugins".
If I connect to the "Generic" controller then it works OK.

What am I missing here?

Also, how does controller discovery work? I've played around with the XSockets.Sample.StockTicker example and noticed "/Stock" is being hit but there's no controller by that exact name - there is a StockController and a StockTickerController class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can probably tell you what wrong if you send me the code (zipped).
The only thing I can think about with the issue is that you have two controllers with the same name (alias). The framework tries to find only one controller with a specific name...
But if you have done what you describe everything should work just fine.

Regarding the StockController and the connection that only uses Stock...
XSockets uses suffix if you want to... So if you have a controller StockController you can connect  to Stock without using the "Controller". If you want to you can use the whole name StockController.

Regards
Uffe

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the last point. 
I moved to the latest version (3.0.0) and it works now. Not sure if it was the version jump or the simple fact that I made a clean build (including manually deleting everything under the 'bin' folder)...!